# My comboboxedit wont display the text that i am setting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What my method does is when you tab or press enter it goes through a method that finds information from another window and after you select that information from the other windows, in this case a person, it fills the text of the combo box with the name of the person. the text in the code is being set but it wont display it

```
private void xbtnsPersonId_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    Object bteCtrl = (Object)sender;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {             
            Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
            ComboBoxEdit mComboBoxEdit = new ComboBoxEdit();
            DashboardPerson vDashboardPerson = xgrdDashboardPerson.SelectedItem as DashboardPerson;

            if (xgrdDashboardPerson.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (vDashboardPerson.DashboardId > 0) { mComboBoxEdit.Uid = vDashboardPerson.DashboardId.ToString(); }
                if (vDashboardPerson.FullName != null) { mComboBoxEdit.Text = vDashboardPerson.FullName; }

                PersonInfoList.FindPerson(ref mComboBoxEdit, true);
                int mPersonId = 0;

                if (((ComboBoxEdit)mComboBoxEdit).Uid != String.Empty)
                {
                    int.TryParse(((ComboBoxEdit)mComboBoxEdit).Uid, out mPersonId);
                    if (mPersonId > 0)
                    {
                    //setting the text from the find person method to the combobox
                    vDashboardPerson.DashboardPersonId = mPersonId;
                    vDashboardPerson.FullName = ((ComboBoxEdit)mComboBoxEdit).Text;
                    }
                }
            }                
    }
}
```

i am also using this piece of code on the XAML side

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xgcPerson" FieldName="FullName" Header="Person" AllowEditing="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings Name="xbtnsPersonId" NullText="Select" AllowDefaultButton="False" KeyDown="xbtnsPersonId_KeyDown" >
            <dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
                <dxe:ButtonInfo x:Name="xbtePersonId" Content="Search" GlyphKind="Search" Click="xbtePersonId_Click" ButtonKind="Simple"/>
            </dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: Its unclear what is not being set, do you mean the data is not getting into the VM or that the control, if so which control, (fullname?) is not being set. Regardless I recommend you create a stand alone project and try to recreate the scenario. Either it will show you what is wrong and fix the problem in the main app, or allow you to post an example here on SO which we can actually run/debug.

Comment: i am using the 'comboboxedit' control, and im using 'PreviewKeyDown' to call my method 'xbtnsPersonId_KeyDown' my method is suppose to set the text inside the 'comboboxedit' depending on what you click in another window. my issue is that its setting the text according to the code but its not displaying the full name of the person i clicked in the previous window, but it says the full name was set into the 'comboboxedit' when i run through the code

Comment: Does full name have a Property Change notification?

Comment: no it does not have it

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing how the propagation of the data is supposed to occur. Unless someone else has an insight, if you could create a test app and use that for us to work off of, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve by problem by making the tab keydown cycle through the grid using the following code

```
private void view1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key != Key.Tab)
        return;
    var currentColumnIndex = grid.Columns.IndexOf(grid.CurrentColumn as GridColumn);
    var newColumnIndex = ++currentColumnIndex % grid.Columns.Count;
    grid.CurrentColumn = grid.Columns[newColumnIndex];
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This allowed tab to enter focusedcolumnchanged and it ended up fixing my issue.